# Interactive function to convert Windows path to POSIX path

Tags: buffers, commands

Here at 'dayjob I'm often sent paths from developers using Windows in Windows format:

```
D:\Some\Path
```

These paths can uniformly be converted to paths valid on at least some Linux machines at 'dayjob like:

```
/mnt/remote-d/Some/Path
```

I would like to write an interactive function to automate this conversion, so that I may simply tap something along the lines of `C-t C-p` to perform this conversion. The string transformation part of the function will probably be something along the lines of

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\" "/" str)
```

But then we also have to capture the string from the buffer. For that purpose `thing-at-point` looks promising, but I've thus far been unable to tame it. I have also found the following function which I think captures what I'm after with some modification: https://github.com/akicho8/string-inflection/blob/master/string-inflection.el#L184

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If the difficulty is capturing a path around point, look at what `ffap` does.

Comment: I was not able to comprehend ffap, it was very confusing to me. But I was able to figure out string-inflection and wrap it to my will.

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to construct a function based on the code in string-inflection.

```
(defconst path-characters "a-zA-Z0-9:\\\\_-")

(defun win-to-posix-posix-path ()
  "Rewrites a Windows formatted path to be of POSIX style."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((start (if mark-active
                    (region-end)
                  (progn
                    (skip-chars-forward path-characters)
                    (point))))
         (end (if mark-active
                  (region-beginning)
                (progn
                  (skip-chars-backward path-characters)
                  (point))))
         (str (buffer-substring start end))
         (slash-fix (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\"  "/"       str))
         (m-fix     (replace-regexp-in-string "[Mm]:" "/mnt/m"  slash-fix t))
         (v-fix     (replace-regexp-in-string "[Vv]:" "/mnt/v"  mls-fix   t)))
    (delete-region start end)
    (insert v-fix)))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the file path you can try:

```
(let ((thing-at-point-file-name-chars
       (concat thing-at-point-file-name-chars "\\")))
  (thing-at-point 'filename))
```